# unable to resolve dependency tree due to react-navigation in my expo app

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, react-navigation

im have to setup an old expo project, and it throws this error when i npm install

```
npm ERR! Found: @react-navigation/native@5.9.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/native@"^5.9.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/native-stack@6.9.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native-stack
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/native-stack@"^6.9.11" from the root project
```

my package.json

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.7",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.11",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.2",
"@taboola/react-native-plugin-3x": "^3.0.7",
```

cant use --force, or --legacy-peer-deps since they cause breaking changes in the rest of my project, how can i resolve these conflicts?